# How to group data by title?

Tags: c#, gridview, binary, selected

I have a SQL table:

```html
ID || Title  || FileName || Extension || FileContent

1  || flower ||rose      || jpg       || binary data

2  || flower ||tulip     || jpg       || binary data

3  || cats   ||black-c   || png       || binary data

4  || cats   ||White-c   || jpg       || binary data

5  || Dogs   ||Brown-d   || jpg       || binary data
```

I want to display all the Pictures with the same title in one row.
So for example, the Title flowers contains to Pictures, etc.

I also have a gridview:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="gridview" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" Width="100%"  GridLines="None" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#a8c066" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />       
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" SortExpression="FileName" />   
     <asp:BoundField DataField="FileContent" HeaderText="FileContent" SortExpression="FileContent" visible="false" />       
       </Columns>
</asp:Gridview>
```

So my Goal is it to selected a row and click on it. If the Title of the selected row is "flower" than it should load the 2 Images.

**WHAT I ALREADY DID/TRIED**

```html
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               GridView listBox = sender as GridView;
               int selectedID =  Int32.Parse(listBox.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString()); 
               LoadDetail(selectedID);
           }
```

```html
 void LoadDetail(int id)
            {

                    List<Pic> sb = (from x in myEnt.Pic where x.ID == id select x).ToList();

                    lblTitle.Text = String.Join(", ", sb.Select(x => x.Title));
                    Img1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/jpg;base64," + String.Join(", ", sb.Select(x => Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])x.FileContent)));
        }
```

It only Shows one Picture, (because of the selected id) but I dont know how to mention the title too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using both columns in DataKeys:

```
DataKeyNames="ID,Title">

var id = listBox.DataKeys[listBox.SelectedIndex].Values["ID"];
var title = listBox.DataKeys[listBox.SelectedIndex].Values["Title"];
```

Comment: @Olga Did you pass `title` to `LoadDetail`?

Comment: `List<Pic> sb = (from x in myEnt.Pic where x.Title == title select x).ToList();`

Comment: tried it. I just get the selected title in muliple forms. So if i select row with title= flower, I get flower, flower. I select title=cats, I get cats, cats,....